# check whether string is within a csv and run a absolute MAX formula using python

Tags: python, string, csv

I have run into a problem with trying to read several csv's and finding a specific string within these csv's and be able to run a formula on it.

The csv all have the following main fields (waterlevel, flow ID and a value):

Water Level, Flow, Water Level,Flow
NEU_NEU_065,NEU_NEU_065,NEU_NEU_065,NEU_NEU_065

(274.4925,**0**,261.3318,**-3.2**)

With the example above there are duplicates for (NEU_NEU_065) for flow which are one value is 0 and another value being -3.2. I manually find and search within this csv this ID and do a Absolute MAX formula on that column range. So for this case I manually take out NEU_NEU_065 and make it NEU_NEU_065a = 0 and the second one NEU_NEU_065 make it NEU_NEU_065b = 3.2.

I don't need to run absolute max on all IDS within the csv just the particular list of IDs I have in another sheet. By running Absoltute max on everything within the csv will not give the right result because it will consider NEU_NEU_065 as one ID and the value will just be = 0. Which is not correct for what I am trying to achieve. I need to extract it out as NEU_NEU_065a = 0 and NEU_NEU_065b = 3.2 (absolute max of -3.2).

import csv

ifile  = open('BCC_R_002c_E_00005Y_0090m_5m_01_PO.csv', "rb")

reader = csv.reader(ifile)

rownum = 0

for row in reader:

```
# Save header row.
if rownum == 0:
    header = row

else:
    colnum = 0
    for col in row:
        print '%-8s: %s' % (header[colnum], col)
        colnum += 1

rownum += 1
```

ifile.close()

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve : do you want to get the maximum absolute value per flow id, or the maximum across all ids ? 
Plus the csv template that you gave is weird, the number of headers doesn't match the number of columns.
You should edit your post so we can help you better.

Comment: Your data "example" is plainly, completely and utterly impossible to understand

Comment: I have updated it above hope its more clear.

Comment: Please provide some code as a starting point.

Comment: All the code does at the moment is read the csv and show results. I am very novice to this so any help will be much appreaciated.